# Installing Ubuntu and Macbook trackpad doesn't work

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, macbook-pro

I'm installing Ubuntu with LiveUSB on my Macbook Pro, but somehow the mouse trackpad doesn't work. The cursor is not appearing at all, and the keypad is not working as well.

So I'm stuck with the very first step of the installation, setting the language. 
There's literally nothing I can do to continue the process.

Does anyone know what to do? Or any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in an external keyboard and mouse?